# react, set state from select options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app I have two components which show perfectly fine, and I've now added a state boolean to each so that i can control when they show.

The issue is that I want to control this with a select/dropdown and i'm a bit stuck

I currently have this block of code and the true/false values on my state correctly affect the showing/hiding of the components, but how can I properly make the select box work so that if i select Net Calories it sets renderCalories to true, and if I select Cholesterol it sets renderCholesterol to true?

```
const handleChange = event => {
setState(event.target.value);
};

class TrendsComponent extends Component {

state = {
  renderCalories: false,
  renderCholesterol: false,
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
    {this.state.renderCalories && <NetCalorieTrend />}
    {this.state.renderCholesterol && <CholesterolTrend />}

    <div className={css(styles.TrendsComponent)}>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={age}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <MenuItem value={10}>Net Calories</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Cholesterol</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleChange` should be a method inside `TrendsComponent` and it should be `this.setState({...})`

```
class TrendsComponent extends Component {

state = {
  renderCalories: false,
  renderCholesterol: false,
}

handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({
     renderCalories: event.target.value === '10', // typeof event.target.value === sting NOT a number
     renderCholesterol: event.target.value === '20'
   });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
    {this.state.renderCalories && <NetCalorieTrend />}
    {this.state.renderCholesterol && <CholesterolTrend />}

    <div className={css(styles.TrendsComponent)}>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={age}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        <MenuItem value={10}>Net Calories</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Cholesterol</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This makes sense and it works, but I have one more question. If I were to take the div with the select and put it in it's own component which I imported here, how would I have to change the handleChange call?

Comment: you can pass `handleChange` as a prop to the child. Then you can call that directly `onChange={this.props.handleChange}` or you can also call it within a method of that component. e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-heisenberg-ejtyr

Answer (score 0):

So first thing first:

```
{this.state.renderCalories && <NetCalorieTrend />}
{this.state.renderCholesterol && <CholesterolTrend />}
```

Do this:

```
{this.state.renderComponent ? <NetCalorieTrend /> : <CholesterolTrend />}
```

Put your handler inside the class and now toggle state value with handler:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
        renderComponent: event.target.value == 10
    })
}
```

*Thanks me later.
Happy Coding!*